# IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 8. When i'm giving 9 instead of 8 it works but accuracy is too low

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, keras

i've made a matrix by concatenating the traing images

```
A = np.concatenate((folder[0], folder[1], folder[2], folder[3], folder[4], folder[5],folder[6], folder[7]))
```

I've defined a matrix which is a label for the images in the matrix A. Each row of the matrix represents the training images. To label all the rows in the
matrix, i have defined a matrix of size 3777 × 1. The values in the matrix are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 to label the rows 1 to 1719, 1720 to 1920, 1921 to 2036, 2037 to 2103, 2104 to 2568, 2568 to 2868, 2868 to 3044, 3044 to 3778 respectively. The code is the
following
actually my folder contains 8 files and this is the labelling i've done.

```
 label = np.ones(3777,dtype = int)
 label[0:1720] = 1
 label[1720:1920] = 2
 label[1920:2038] = 3
 label[2038:2104] = 4
 label[2104:2568] = 5
 label[2568:2868] = 6
 label[2868:3044] = 7
 label[3044:3778] = 8
 data,Label = shuffle(A,label,random_state=2)
```

The labelling is done on the basis of this data 1719×65536, 200×65536, 117×65536, 67×65536, 465×65536, 299×65536, 176×65536, 734×65536.

My code comes like this.

```
labelled_data = [data, Label]
X,Y = [labelled_data[0],labelled_data[1]]

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.4, 
random_state=4)

x_test, x_validation, y_test, y_validation=train_test_split(X_test, Y_test, test_size=0.5,
random_state=4)
import numpy as np


print(X_train.shape)
```

the output is:

(2266, 196608)

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0],256,256,3))
x_validation = x_validation.reshape((x_validation.shape[0],256,256,3))
x_test =x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0],256,256,3))


X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')

X_train = X_train/255
x_validation = x_validation/255
x_test =x_test/255

from keras.utils import np_utils
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train,8)
y_validation =np_utils.to_categorical(y_validation,8)
y_test =np_utils.to_categorical(y_test,8)
```

i'm getting en error like this

```
  IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-af19e709e58b> in <module>
      1 from keras.utils import np_utils
----> 2 Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train,8)
      3 y_validation =np_utils.to_categorical(y_validation,8)
      4 y_test =np_utils.to_categorical(y_test,8)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py in to_categorical(y, num_classes, dtype)
     50     n = y.shape[0]
     51     categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes), dtype=dtype)
---> 52     categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
     53     output_shape = input_shape + (num_classes,)
     54     categorical = np.reshape(categorical, output_shape)

IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 8
```

when i'm giving 9 instead of 8, it's running fine,but i'm getting very low accuracy and i'm not getting the confusion_matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Class indices start from zero, not from one:

```
 label = np.ones(3777,dtype = int)
 label[0:1720] = 0
 label[1720:1920] = 1
 label[1920:2038] = 2
 label[2038:2104] = 3
 label[2104:2568] = 4
 label[2568:2868] = 5
 label[2868:3044] = 6
 label[3044:3778] = 7
```

This should also provide meaningful accuracies, as the model predicts class indices also starting from zero.